# Blender inserts keyframes on multiple channels but I want it on one

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

Now this is probably a beginners thing that I have missed. I am trying to animate this object first on the z rotation and then on the y rotation. Whenevever I select the keyframe to move it and it appears to have inserted on multiple channels and overlayed it ontop of the other keyframes. How can I just insert a single keyframe on say the z rotation and be able to move them separately on one channel? I am really confused.

These images should help explain my situation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAooI.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzGXb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgalL.jpg

Mark

Answer (score 2):

In order to set a keyframe on an individual channel, simply right-click the property and right-click and select 'Insert Single Keyframe'.

[image: Insert Single Keyframe]

Alternatively, you can click on the Animate Property 'dot' alongside the property in the right-hand properties panel :

[image: click animate property]

In the Dope Sheet, you can move individual channel keyframes by simply selecting the keyframe for that specific channel only - and move it independently of any other channel(s).

[image: dope sheet move keyframe one channel]